# migx при создании статьи автоматически создаёт тег <p>

Tags: javascript, php, modx

migx при создании статьи автоматически создаёт тег `<p>` как это исправить ?

Comment: migx это объединение нескольких полей TV в один, смотрите какие там поля объединяются и их характеристики, возможно в каком-то из этих полей указано значение по умолчанию, либо приведите текст migx

Comment: Используйте [mutationObserver](https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer)

Answer (score 0):

Почти наверняка для вывода содержимого MIGX используется  сниппет [getImageList](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/migx/migx.frontend-usage), если это так -изучите содержимое чанка,указанного в параметре &tpl, вероятно тег

появляется оттуда. Второй вариант - возможно для вывода используется поле типа richtext, в режиме редактирования это может быть не заметно, но при выводе в код попадает "обертка" визуального редактора, тег